# What datatype is being used here?

Tags: python, types

I stumbled across this working code in Python but I am unsure on how to use that datatype.

```
global_widgets = {}



def register_widget(self, widget_object):
    if widget_object.gid not in self.global_widgets:
        self.global_widgets[widget_object.gid] = widget_object

def get_widget(self, widget_gid):
    if widget_gid in self.global_widgets:
        return self.global_widgets[widget_gid]
    else:
        return None
```

I am new but I assume that the used Datatype is like a HashMap in Java.
Is my assumption right that this datatype maps any value to a string (`widget_object.gid`) and that `global_widgets[???]` the question tags can be replaced with any datatype and not just numbers?

Comment: its a dictionary... effectivly a hashmap in other languages... the key can be any hashable datatype (tuple/string/int/float/etc)

Comment: Time to read a python tutorial.

Comment: This can help you in the future: you can start by, for example, printing the type of a variable with `print type(your_variable)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`global_widgets` is a python dictionary.  This is analogous to a `HashMap` in Java, except with a few subtle differences since these are two different languages